# Why cannot the QML webengineview specify cache path and storage path?

Tags: qml, qwebengineview

```
WebEngineProfile{
    id:weProfile;
    cachePath: cppApp.currentDir()+'/cache';
    persistentCookiesPolicy:WebEngineProfile.ForcePersistentCookies;
    persistentStoragePath:cppApp.currentDir()+'/storage';
}
```

This is the settings of my profile. I have created both the "cache" folder and "storage" folder, and cppApp.currentDir() returns the current directory.

I have also set the profile of WebEngineView in QML

```
profile:weProfile;
```

These directory settings did not achieve the expected effect, and there were no caches or cookies present in these two directories. However, there is a difference between not using a profile. Without a profile, cookies will be recorded (although they are in another folder), but with this profile, cookies will never be recorded.

I don't know where I made a mistake. I tested this on ubuntu 22.04 with qt version 5.15.3, and on win10 with qt version 5.15.2

I have tried adding

```
offTheRecord: false;
storageName: "xxx";
httpCacheType: WebEngineProfile. DiskHttpCache;
```

to the profile. But none of these works.

Comment: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-108044 Apparently, with Qt 5.13.0 default value of offTheRecord is changed from false to true.

Comment: @iam_peter thank you! After adding both offTheRecord and storageName, it's OK. I think I didn't add them together before.